# ElasticSearch - How to get current date and time?

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch

Is it possible to get current date and time from Elastic Search (preferably in Java API)?

I've searched everywhere and for quite some time but found only that Range Queries can perform math on some date fields and it's possible to use script fields but I couldn't find any script for returning current date. All I'm asking for is something similar to SQL's now().

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you need that? That's an unusual request.

Comment: We are doing application clustering and I need to make sure that all clusters operate on the same date and time. Everything works fine and dandy in other projects that use regular databases (and their date/time).

Comment: That kind of thing/synch is usually done at the system level (using ntp and the like), isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, what @Val said. You don't need Elasticsearch to tell you that.

Comment: Alright, so out of curiosity now (because I'm kinda surprised I couldn't find anything), there's no way to get current time from elastic?

Comment: No, just what you found so far `now()` or inside groovy/painless scripts inside queries or aggregations.

Answer (score 8):

In Sense (you didn't specify an ES version; this works against 2.3.2):

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "script_fields": {
    "now": {
      "script": "new Date().getTime()"
    }
  }
}
```

In the Java API, it'd be something like (not tested):

```
yourSearchRequestBuilder.addScriptField("now", "new Date().getTime()");
```

This does require that there's at least 1 doc in `your_index` so that there's something to hang the script field off; it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Actually in Elastic 8.3.2 there is no need to specify any `your_index` in the search. Simple `GET _search` works as well.